# Webpack 2 compiling but not running javascript

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I have 2 JS files

**Index.js**

```
const sum = require('./app');

const total = sum(10,5);

console.log(total);
```

**app.js**

```
function sum(a,b){
  return a+b;
}
module.exports = sum;
```

**webpack config**

```
const path = require('path');

const config ={
  entry:"./app/index.js",
  output:{
    path:path.resolve(__dirname,"app/build"),
    filename:'bundle.js'
  }
}

module.exports = config;
```

The bundle.js is getting generated , i have added the bundle to my index.html, the bundle also gets loaded when checking in network tab. But the `console.log(total)` is not working, nothing works.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing showed up in you browser console? Any errors?
Maybe it would be better to show us your configuration ( eg: webpack command or/and your package.json )?

Your code works fine with this configuration :

[image]

```
app
├── app.js
├── build
│   ├── bundle.js
│   └── index.html
└── index.js
```

webpack.config.js :

```
const path = require('path');

const config ={
  entry:"./app/index.js",
  output:{
    path:path.resolve(__dirname,"app/build"),
    filename:'bundle.js'
  }
}

module.exports = config;
```

package.json :

```
{
  "name": "stackof",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack -d --watch"
  },
  "author": "Marwen <marwen_no_spam_pls@gmail.com> (http://www.gameole.com)",
  "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "2.2.1"
  }
}
```

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>title from webpack</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

To generate the bundle you just need to execute :

```
npm run dev
```

Comment: Ok, something was wrong.. it was not working for 2-3 hrs , now suddenly it works ... thanks anyways

Comment: Maybe a problem of cache -browser caching a broken version of your code- :-) Anyways if this solved your issue don't forgot to accept the answer ;)

Comment: cache -browser caching was the issue in my case